# Node.js, mongoose, express - cannot get result from a mongoose schema method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user schema as shown below:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    resetToken: {
      type: String    
    }
})
```

Below is a mongoose schema method I define beneath the schema definition:

```
userSchema.methods.generateResetToken = function() { 
  const reset_token = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
  bcrypt.hash(reset_token, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return winston.error(err.message)
    return hash
  })
}
```

Here is a snippet of code from my signup route:

```
user = new User(_.pick(req.body, ['username', 'email', 'password']))

bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return winston.error(err.message)

    // Getting undefined logged here 
    console.log(user.generateResetToken())

    user.password = hash
    user.save()
})
```

When calling `console.log(user.generateResetToken())` I expect the returned value from the `generateResetToken` function to be printed. Instead I get `undefined` printed. I can confirm that a `hash` is being generated as I logged the `hash` to the console, and everything worked fine.

Does anybody know why I am getting `undefined` here in my signup route when calling the `generateResetToken` function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently not returning anything from the `generateResetToken` method. You can pass a callback to the function as below

```js
userSchema.methods.generateResetToken = function(callback) { 
  const reset_token = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
  bcrypt.hash(reset_token, 10, callback)
}
```

Now you can make a call to the method as below

```js
user.generateResetToken(function(err, hash) {
    if (err) winston.error(err.message)
    console.log(hash)
  }))
```

Also can use `async/await`

```js
userSchema.methods.generateResetToken = async function() { 
  const reset_token = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
  return bcrypt.hash(reset_token, 10)
}
```

```js
  try {
    const hash  = await myRec.generateResetToken();
  } catch (err) {
    winston.error(err.message)
  }
```